# mysql_num_rows or mysqli_num_rows reasons for returning false

Tags: php, mysql

What are all the possible scenarios for `mysql_num_rows` or `mysqli_num_rows` to return `false`? Is there anywhere in the source code I can look?

The only one I can think of is if `mysql_query` was invalid or didn't return a result. Is there any other reasons?

The reason I ask is I am trying to debug a very odd error where the query is valid, but `mysql(i)_num_rows` is returning `false`. (My best guess of what is happening as it has only happened once and I didn't have all the logging in place)

Comment: `mysql_error()` or `mysqli_error()` should tell you the reason.

Comment: try mysql_query('your sql query') or die('Problem with query'); mysql_num_rows returns FALSE only when there is a failure for query

Comment: I'm not exactly sure how you are using your code, however try using it like this: `$NumberOfRows = mysqli_num_rows(mysqli_query($yourConnection, "YOUR QUERY"));`

As an example for a query, one of the queries I used for my website was `"SELECT * FROM my_table WHERE id = '$myId'"`

Comment: What kind of query do you execute? some queries just return true instead of a result set.

Comment: If the query failed, the argument to `mysql_num_rows` will be `false`, which should cause an error to be reported about a wrong argument type. Make sure you have error reporting enabled.

Comment: The only other thing I can think of is if the connection to the database server fails between `mysql_query` and `mysql_num_rows`.

Comment: Please provide your query

Comment: Since this function retrieves the number of rows from a result set it's only valid for SELECT or SHOW statements. So, I guess you didn't use it with INSERT, UPDATE or DELETE statements.

Comment: It is a select statement that is somehow returning 0 or false when there is a row. It happened once in a month and I cannot determine why. I am basically waiting for it to happen again.